# Packets passing thru two routers DNATing them, source IP is lost

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a xen machine (`DomU`) hosting a few VMs.

One of the VMs is called `router` (10.0.0.1) and is the only one of the machines supposed to be reachable from the outside.

There are other VMs which are going to recieve traffic, but it has to be filtered.
Let's call one of these machines `web` (10.0.0.2), as it serves a webpage.

Packets coming to `web` follow this routing path:

`xen DomU` -> `router` -> `web`

`DomU`'s configuration:

```
-A PREROUTING -d <external_ip> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.1:80 
-A POSTROUTING -o xenbr0 -j MASQUERADE
```

`router`'s configuration:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 10.0.0.1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.0.2:80 
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Everything works as expected.

Port 80 from the external IP is routed via `router` all the way to `web`.

There is a problem tho:
`web` sees `10.0.0.1` as the source for the connection, rather than the real client IP.

I guess this is caused by the fact that there are two DNATing iptables.

But why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using MASQUERADE is for NATting a source address to a public IP; you should *NOT* masquerade traffic coming from the internet, which it seems you are likely doing.

Therefore, remove your MASQUERADE rules entirely or, if you need them to provide internet access to internal clients, restrict the MASQUERADE to a specific subnet

Comment: I've added changed the masquerade line to:
`-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE` so now it should only masquerdate traffic that should be routed from the internal subnet thru this machine. I thought -o eth0 was doing that, but the machine was routing all traffic thru eth0. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MASQUERADE statement on "router" is, uh, masquerading the external IP as it comes through "router".